# Unable to ssh login from windows to ubuntu

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty

I am trying to login on my ubuntu server from windows pc using putty ssh but it says connection refused.

I am able lo login on ubuntu using command

> $ ssh root@MY-IP-ADDRESS

not able to login using remote server.

Please Help me.

Comment: from the Windows machine try: ping MY-IP-ADDRESS. Than try "telnet MY-IP-ADDRESS 22". Are you able to ping the machine? are you able to connect to port 22? Is there a firewall running on the ubuntu machine?

Comment: `ssh -v root@MY-IP_ADDRESS` v=verbose, it will output lots messages allow you to have an idea what is going on

Comment: This is not a programmation question, please post on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and nothing was working for me to connect to ec2 linux instance from Windows 7.  Here is how i was finally able to connect.

1.)  Download [puttygen.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and create a .ppk file from your .pem file that you downloaded from amazon.
2.)  Use FireSSH (plug-in for Firefox), put in your host name, use 'ubuntu' (minus the quotes) for the Login, leave password blank and enter the location of the .ppk you created from puttygen.exe

Note:  Oddly enough i was not able to connect using putty.exe but the private key it generates works fine with FireSSH

Comment: that worked great for me!  Thanks!  I also had the same problem with the putty.exe.  Why did they have to make this so hard?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install openssh-server ?

```
   aptitude install openssh-server
```

Then also check you don't have firewall running on your Ubuntu.

Comment: i have install openssh on my server and able to login on local host but not able to connect remotely from windows.

Comment: do you have a firewall on windows ?

Comment: Perhaps your `ssh` client has the `-v` option (which exists on Linux)?

Comment: the you should disable it completely for outgoing connections or find how to enable outgoing traffic on port 22.